# How can i change filename in c++

Tags: c++, rename, filenames

I want to change Filename.
Program is MVC of c++.

I searched and found some method.
Then, I have tried changing with rename method which in cstdio lib.

I wrote just this one Line.

```
std::rename("C:\\CNV\\Image\\GETDATA\\9KA13103.SLDPRT", "C:\\CNV\\Image\\GETDATA\\9KA13103-02A.SLDPRT");
```

But, that is return -1.

also, I had tried to use other library which filesystem::tr2::sys::rename
But, That was fail too.

All example source which i found in internet to use cstdio::std::rename.
Wrote  just filename in rename method like

```
std::rename("abc.txt", "123.txt");
```

But i thought That is weird what write just filename not included path.
But now, I expect that i have misunderstood about using std::rename.

Please can you tell me How can i do this.
Thank you.

Comment: What does `std::perror` display?  Do you already have a file called `9KA13103-02A.SLDPRT`?  Do you have _modify_ or _write_ permissions in that directory?  Does the original file actually exist?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio is this?

Comment: Robert Prévost // Using Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 1):

paddy // You are right.

The reason was file opened.

I perceived that i had tried to change file name while file opened.
So i Edit that try changing name after closing SolidWorks Process.

Thank you